# Как работать с DSpace на c#?

Tags: c#, облако, хранилище

Собственно существует https://duraspace.org/dspace/ 
Возникла необходимость из c# сохранять файлы в данном хранилище настроенном на сервере организации. Честно не знаю где искать, и даже с чего начать.

Comment: Обычно начинают с того, что курят [доки](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC/All+Documentation)

Comment: в общем-то этим и занимаюсь, читаю https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/REST+API, надеялся что уже существует готовая библиотека, но видимо нет, придется идти по Get и Post запросам, как указано в документации.

Comment: Интересно, но ни одно готового, полуготового клиента на C# на [гитхабе](https://github.com/search?q=dspace+client&type=Repositories) не просматривается. Так что у вас есть возможность стать первопроходцем :)

Comment: Я ошибочно дал название, не DSPase, а DSPace.